# Checking if checkboxes are checked ornot, returns addEventListener is not a function

Tags: javascript, checkbox, onchange

Hi I got the following code snippet where im trying to print a `console.log` dependent on if a checkbox has been checked or not.

```
var checkbox = document.querySelectorAll('.customer-club-widget__gender__categories .form__input-checkbox');

checkbox.addEventListener("change", function() {

    var isChecked = checkbox.checked;
    if(isChecked){ //checked
        console.log('checked');
    }else{ //unchecked
        console.log('unchecked');
    }
});
```

I keep getting the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: `checkbox.addEventListener is not a function` and a cant figure out why this is happening.

Comment: `querySelectorAll` returns an array..

Comment: querSelectorAll returns an array. You need to loop through array and add the listener to all the items. Or just use event delegation.

Comment: `querySelectorAll` returns NodeList. If you want to add listener to each node the nodeList contained in some point in time, you can use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList#Specifications

Comment: `dependent on if a checkbox`, if it's a single checkbox don't use the `All` version, just use `querySelector(` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting the error since **[`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)** return a array of elements and you're trying to attach the event to this array, else you should loop through it to attach the change event to every element inside, like :

```
//Loop through the array elements and attach the event
for (var i = 0; i < checkbox.length; i++) {
  checkbox[i].addEventListener("change", checkedOrNot);
}

//Define separate function
function checkedOrNot() {
  var isChecked = this.checked;

  if (isChecked) { //checked
    console.log('checked');
  } else { //unchecked
    console.log('unchecked');
  }
}
```

Hoep this helps.

```js
var checkbox = document.querySelectorAll('.customer-club-widget__gender__categories .form__input-checkbox');

for (var i = 0; i < checkbox.length; i++) {
  checkbox[i].addEventListener("change", checkedOrNot);
}

function checkedOrNot() {
  var isChecked = this.checked;

  if (isChecked) { //checked
    console.log('checked');
  } else { //unchecked
    console.log('unchecked');
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="customer-club-widget__gender__categories">
  <input type="checkbox" class="form__input-checkbox" /> A
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="form__input-checkbox" /> B
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="form__input-checkbox" /> C 
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="form__input-checkbox" /> D
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// foreach loop over checkbox and call change function

checkbox.forEach(checkbox => {
  checkbox.addEventListener("change", checkboxCheck);
});

function checkboxCheck() {
  var is_checked = this.checked;

  if (is_checked) { //checked
      console.log('checked');
  } else { //unchecked
     console.log('unchecked');
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with a explanation. Code only answers are unhelpful